# What I'm doing wrong with this index identifier function in R?

Tags: r, function, indexing

So I was studying about changing values in R objects such as vectors, lists and Data Frames and I stumbled upon a particular and very useful way of identifying where a particular value is within a Data Frame, using this syntax:

```
"string" == dataframe$column
```

in the console I have this as my return within the scope of the example:

[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[20] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[39] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

The Code I've used to get this result was very simple:

```
"ace" == deck3$"face"
```

Where "deck3" is just a data frame with 3 columns where 1 column is named "face".

The problem that I'm having is this one, when I try to capsulate this syntax in a function I don't have the behavior that I expected, the function I've created:

```
index_identifier <- function(dataframe, text_to_be_changed,column_name){
         text_to_be_changed == dataframe$column_name
}
```

The result, using the same strings is this:

```
index_identifier(deck3,"ace","face")
 return: logical(0)
```

I don't understand where I'm making a mistake, can someone please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: You could try replacing `text_to_be_changed == dataframe$column_name` by `text_to_be_changed == dataframe[column_name]`. This might work.

Comment: The function `which()` takes a logical argument and returns the index number of the values that are TRUE.

Comment: @MartinGal THANK YOU! That chage worked wonders. But I don't understand WHY the way I was doing didn't work.. but anyway thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example, first let's make a reproducible example:

```
face <- c("king", "queen", "jack", "ten", "nine", "eight", "seven", "six", 
     "five", "four", "three", "two", "ace")
suits <- c("spades", "clubs", "diamonds", "hearts")
value <- c(13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
deck <- data.frame(face=rep(face, 4), suits=rep(suits, each=13), 
value=rep(value, 4))
str(deck)
# 'data.frame': 52 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ face : chr  "king" "queen" "jack" "ten" ...
#  $ suits: chr  "spades" "spades" "spades" "spades" ...
#  $ value: num  13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 ...
```

Your question was which cards have "ace" as their face value:

```
which(deck$face =="ace")
# [1] 13 26 39 52
deck[which(deck$face =="ace"), ]
#    face    suits value
# 13  ace   spades     1
# 26  ace    clubs     1
# 39  ace diamonds     1
# 52  ace   hearts     1
```